# Continuous function from real line of the set of all $n \times n$ real matrix.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, matrices, metric-spaces

Let us take usual definitions of continuity on metric spaces and the usual distance metric on $M(n,\mathbb{R})$. I am looking for a continuous mapping $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow M(n, \mathbb{R})$, where $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all real matrix of order $n$.

Does such mapping exists? If not, why? Please explain. Otheswies give me some examples that may me helpful to study the topological properties of $M(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Shall we see any difference if we consider the field $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$?

I know $\det(A)$ and trace$(A)$ are two functions $M(n,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Both of them are continuous, but invers mappings does not exists and so fur from the question of continuity.

I do not know matrix calculus. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you mean a homeomorphism, there isn't any (unless $n=1$).  The space of $n\times n$ real matrices is just $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, and $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ isn't homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ unless $m=n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most general such continuous map is of the form $t\mapsto (a_{ij}(t))$, where $a_{ij}\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function. That is each entry of the matrix can be an arbitrary continuous function.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. Hope it will be enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with $f(x) = xI?$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix)

Comment: Dear Sir, Nothing is wrong. The range of this matrix is very limited, multiple of identity matrix only. I want some more examples, where range may cover other types of matrices like singular matrix, orthogonal, non-orthogonal matrix etc.

Comment: @Samprity Why don't you ask the question you mean to ask, then?

Answer (score 1):

The general topological properties are essentially the same as in $\boldsymbol{R}^{n^2}$.  You may consider the singular matrices: they form a cone in $M(n,\boldsymbol R)$.  Or take $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ or $\mathrm{GL}^+(n,\boldsymbol{R})$: they are path-connected; $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is compact.  Or: for all matrices $A$ with positive determinant there is a $B\in\mathrm{SO}(n)$ and a path $c\colon[0,1]\to\mathrm{GL}^+$ which connects $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Mr. Hoppe. You have properly understood my unattered question that I was hesitating to ask. I was tried to prove them using $\det(A)$ is continuous mapping. Please expand this answer with some hints. to prove those results.

Comment: The general topological properties are not just essentially the same as in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2},$ the space _is_ $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}.$